# Swift MFMessageComposeViewController tint and background color iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to use custom color in `MFMessageComposeViewController`. I thought it will be okay to use:

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
    let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    messageVC.body = "Enter a message";
    messageVC.recipients = [phoneString]
    messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    //color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "fec13e")
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.presentViewController(messageVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

but its not working.

Comment: try before to present the messageVC: `messageVC.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()` and `messageVC.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()`

Comment: @TonyMkenu I did your comment. but it is not working to me.
xcode8 / swift3

Comment: Any solution ? I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I have the same problem, can't find the way to change background color for message composer.

Comment: same issue any solutions ?

Comment: Set navigation appearance color before initialisation of mailcomposerviewcontroller.                  UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.yourcolor()
let mailVC = MFMailComposeViewController()

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to change the color of MFMessageComposeViewController navigation color.

`let size = CGSize(width: (self.window?.frame.size.width)!, height: 64)
let image = self.getImageWithColor(UIColor .init(colorLiteralRed: 40.0/255.0, green: 140.0/255.0, blue: 204.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), size:size)
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets.zero, resizingMode: .stretch), for: .default)`

Where **getImageWithColor** is the func which return image of desired color

`func getImageWithColor(_ color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage
    {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height))
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }`